# Can I force the compiler to fail when some protocol functions change their signature?

Tags: swift, xcode, protocol-extension

Is there a way to mark some Swift functions as implementing some protocol functions so that if the protocol's signature changes, the compiler can mark implementations as an error.

For instance, consider this example where I have a default implementation of the `Foo` protocol for `UIViewController` instances, and I want to override it for a custom `Bar` class that is a subclass of `UIViewController`.

```
// V1
protocol Foo {
    func number() -> Int
}

extension Foo where Self: UIViewController {
    func number() -> Int {
        return 0
    } 
}

// Overrides the default implementation
extension Bar: Foo {
    func number() -> Int {
        return 1
    }
}
```

Now, the protocol evolves to:

```
// V2
protocol Foo {
    func numberV2() -> Int
}

extension Foo where Self: UIViewController {
    func numberV2() -> Int {
        return 0
    } 
}

// I think I override the default implementation but not anymore.
// => error prone, no error from the compiler
extension Bar: Foo {
    func number() -> Int {
        return 1
    }
}
```

How can I help my `Bar` extension be aware that the `number` function is no longer relevant for the `Foo` protocol?

Comment: I don't think there's a way. There's no difference for compiler's perspective to distinguish a method and a protocol method.

Comment: One thing you can do is, the function must be unused function because you change the name. If you use `swiftlinter` like tool, you can find that kind of function while build time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there's currently (Swift 4.0) no way to get help from the compiler for catching these "near misses". This topic has come up several times on the swift-evolution mailing list, though, so people are definitely aware that it's a problem that should be solved.

In fact, Doug Gregor recently [made a change](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/12645) to the Swift compiler that will able to catch some "near misses". The change is not part of the current Swift release, but will be in Swift 4.1.

From [the mailing list post](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-dev/Week-of-Mon-20171023/005728.html) introducing the change:

> A “near-miss” warning fires when there is a protocol conformance for which:
>
> 1) One of the requirements is satisfied by a “default” definition (e.g., one from a protocol extension), and
>
> 2) There is a member of the same nominal type declaration (or extension declaration) that declared the conformance that has the same name as the requirement and isn’t satisfying another requirement.
>
> These are heuristics, of course, and we can tune the heuristics over time.

If I understand this correctly, the current heuristics won't catch your exact issue because they only match methods with the exact same name (but differing types), but as Doug said the heuristics may be improved in the future.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the reasons default protocol implementations should be as specific as possible if the functionality will ever be overridden.

As previously mentioned there isn't a direct way to do this, but I'll give a few work arounds.

- Have 2 protocols, one with the default implementation and one without. e.g.  `AutoFoo: Foo` and `Foo`. Have the default implementation on `AutoFoo`, and have Bar only adhere to `Foo` so as to not be affected by `AutoFoo`'s default implementation.
- Use a refactoring engine when changing names (the built in Xcode engine *should* work)
- Change the name in the protocol, build, then find all the places with errors.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining an extension of your protocol that manages objects of type `UIViewController`, you could instead, provide a `UIViewController` root class that implements your `Foo` protocol and uses subclasses for all other `UIViewController` that needs to implements `Foo`.

Explaining that with code:

Your `Foo` protocol :

```
protocol Foo {
    func number() -> Int
}
```

Here is how the `Root` class looks like:

```
class Root: UIViewController, Foo {
    func number() -> Int {
        return 1
    }
}
```

And your overrided implementation of the subclass:

```
class Bar: Root {
    override func number() -> Int {
        return 5
    }
}
```

Each time you change the method signature of your `Foo` protocol the compiler will throw an error, against the `Root` class because it doesn't conforms anymore to the `Foo` protocol and against the `Bar` subclass (once you've fixed this error) because it doesn't override any method of `Root` anymore.

And for classes for which you don't need to override `Foo` you can just inherit from `Root` and it will use the default implementation:

```
class Joe: Root {
}
```

Full code (Before):

```
protocol Foo {
    func number() -> Int
}

extension Foo where Self: UIViewController {
    func number() -> Int {
        return 0
    }
}

// Class with an overrided implementation of the number() method.
class Bar: UIViewController, Foo {
  func number() -> Int {
      return 1
  }
}

// Class uses the default implementation of the number() method.
class Joe: UIViewController, Foo {

}
```

Full code (After):

```
protocol Foo {
    func number() -> Int
}

class Root: UIViewController, Foo {
    func number() -> Int {
        return 1
    }
}

// Class with an overrided implementation of the number() method.
class Bar: Root {
    override func number() -> Int {
        return 5
    }
}

// Class uses the default implementation of the number() method.
class Joe: Root {
}
```

Hope it helps.